# Gulp установка пакета bootstrap

Tags: gulp

Народ, добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как установить и подключить к своему проекту bootstrap через Gulp. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: прошу вас ознакомиться с системой сборки gulp, будете понимать что это и как работает, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDyvV36pndZFLTE13V4qNWTZbeipNhCgQ . многие вопросы отпадут сами собой. например как автоматически подключать устанавливаемы библиотеки

Answer (score 2):

Gulp - это плагин NodeJS. Через него вы не установите бутстрап.

Вы можете установит пакетный менеджер `Bower` и после этого установить Bootstrap командой:

```
$ bower i bootstrap
```

Для сохранении зависимости, используйте флаг `--save`:

```
$ bower i bootstrap --save
```

Comment: Я использую TARS (https://github.com/tars/tars-cli). Он на Gulp. Даже если я установлю его как вы написали, как он подключится к проекту ?